# Is it possible to have Hygieia dashboard url in https://<ipaddress>:<portnumber>/

Tags: virtual-machine, dashboard

I have installed and setup hygieia in my vm, so is it possible to shift url from http to https.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. Initially, web apps uses http. You may use SSL certificates for your https.